# Resize a ByteArray or a GrayScale Image

Tags: c#, image

I'd like to resize a `ByteArray` from `[5x7]` to `[241x301]` pixels using bicubic/biquadratic interpolation. Therefore, I tried to convert the `ByteArray` to a `Bitmap` with pixelformat `Format16bppGrayScale`. Then, I tried to convert the resized `Bitmap` back to another `ByteArray`.

Unfortunately, it seems that GDI does not support the conversion of the format `Format16bppGrayScale`. I always get Exceptions, such as `invalid argument`, or `out of memory`. I queried this on Google but I only found [this similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e1c00ee3-0f0d-4eb3-a928-7ee23204c2dc/resize-a-16-bit-grayscale-bytearray?forum=csharplanguage), which suggests to either use a 3rd party library or to write my own code to resize using the byte array.

Can anyone suggest a method to get a resized byte array?

**UPDATE**

The following code example gives me a `System.ArgumentException`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] resizedBitmap = resizeImage(new byte[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } }, 241, 301);
}

public static Byte[] resizeImage(byte[,] matrix, int width, int height)
{
    // Create Bitmap from ByteArray
    Bitmap original;
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (byte* intPtr = &matrix[0, 0])
        {
            original = new Bitmap(5, 7, 4, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale, new IntPtr(intPtr));
        }
    }

    // Resize the Bitmap and convert it back to a ByteArray
    Image newImage = new Bitmap(241, 301);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Bicubic;

        // Convert the Bitmap back to a ByteArray
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(241, 301, g);
        BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(), bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
        byte[] dataAsBytes = new byte[bmpData.Stride * bmpData.Height];
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, dataAsBytes, 0, dataAsBytes.Length);
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        return dataAsBytes;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the source code you are using to resize and produces the error? A 241x301 bitmap should not produce an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: I've removed the part where you ask for a third-party library as to avoid your question getting closed.

Comment: Oh thanks! And sorry! I'll add a code example in a minute

Comment: _Unfortunately, it seems that GDI does not support the conversion of the format Format16bppGrayScale_ That's right. Can't you simply use another format ?

Comment: I guess that I could put my ByteArray in one of the three RGB values and leave the other two channels constant. However, I was hoping that there would be another method.

Comment: To at least make it look greyscale put the same value in each channel! You didn't tell us what you actually want to do with the image: display, save to file, to DB, print...

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the GDI+ interpolation to perform the resize:

```
        Image original = new Bitmap(/* path to your 5x7 image */);
        Image newImage = new Bitmap(241, 301);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Bicubic;
            g.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height));
        }
```